# how can I partition a line into code and comment using a single regex in perl?

Tags: perl, hashtable, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want to read through a text file and partition each line into the following three variables. Each variable must be defined, although it might be equal to the empty string.

- `$a1code`: all characters up to and not including the first non-escaped percent sign. If there is no non-escaped percent sign, this is the entire line. As we see in the example below, this also could be the empty string in a line where the following two variables are non-empty.
- `$a2boundary`: the first non-escaped percent sign, if there is one.
- `$a3cmnt`: any characters after the first non-escaped percent sign, if there is one.

The script below accomplishes this but requires several lines of code, two hashes, and a composite regex, that is, 2 regex combined by `|`.
The composite seems necessary because the first clause,

```
(?<a1code>.*?)(?<a2boundary>(?<!\\)%)(?<a3cmnt>.*)
```

does not match a line that is pure code, no comment.
Is there a more elegant way, using a single regex and fewer steps?
In particular, is there a way  to dispense with the `%match` hash and somehow
fill the `%+` hash with all three three variables in a single step?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
print join('', 'perl ', $^V, "\n",);
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper); $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my $count=0;
while(<DATA>)
{
    $count++;
    print "$count\t";
    chomp;
    my %match=(
        a2boundary=>'',
        a3cmnt=>'',
    );
    print "|$_|\n";
    if($_=~/^(?<a1code>.*?)(?<a2boundary>(?<!\\)%)(?<a3cmnt>.*)|(?<a1code>.*)/)
    {
        print "from regex:\n";
        print Dumper \%+;
        %match=(%match,%+,);
    }
    else
    {
        die "no match? coding error, should never get here";
    }
    if(scalar keys %+ != scalar keys %match)
    {
        print "from multiple lines of code:\n";
        print Dumper \%match;
    }
    print "------------------------------------------\n";
}

__DATA__
This is 100\% text and below you find an empty line.

abba 5\% %comment 9\% %Borgia
%all comment
%
```

Result:

```
perl v5.34.0
1   |This is 100\% text and below you find an empty line.   |
from regex:
$VAR1 = {
          'a1code' => 'This is 100\\% text and below you find an empty line.   '
        };
from multiple lines of code:
$VAR1 = {
          'a1code' => 'This is 100\\% text and below you find an empty line.   ',
          'a2boundary' => '',
          'a3cmnt' => ''
        };
------------------------------------------
2   ||
from regex:
$VAR1 = {
          'a1code' => ''
        };
from multiple lines of code:
$VAR1 = {
          'a1code' => '',
          'a2boundary' => '',
          'a3cmnt' => ''
        };
------------------------------------------
3   |abba 5\% %comment 9\% %Borgia|
from regex:
$VAR1 = {
          'a1code' => 'abba 5\\% ',
          'a2boundary' => '%',
          'a3cmnt' => 'comment 9\\% %Borgia'
        };
------------------------------------------
4   |%all comment|
from regex:
$VAR1 = {
          'a1code' => '',
          'a2boundary' => '%',
          'a3cmnt' => 'all comment'
        };
------------------------------------------
5   |%|
from regex:
$VAR1 = {
          'a1code' => '',
          'a2boundary' => '%',
          'a3cmnt' => ''
        };
------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about cases like `this\\%string` where the backslash before the percent sign is itself escaped?

Consider something like this, which instead of trying to use a regular expression to split the string into three groups, uses one to look where for it should be split, and `substr` to do the actual splitting:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub splitter {
    my $line = shift;
    if ($line =~ /
       # Match either
       (?<!\\)% # A % not preceded by a backslash    
       | # or                    
       (?<=[^\\])(?:\\\\)+\K% # Any even number of backslashes followed by a %
                 /x) {
        return (substr($line, 0, $-[0]), '%', substr($line, $+[0]));        
    } else {
        return ($line, '', '');
    }
}

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    # Assign to an array instead of individual scalars for demonstration purposes
    my @vals = splitter $_;
    print Dumper(\@vals);
}   

__DATA__
This is 100\% text and below you find an empty line.

abba 5\% %comment 9\% %Borgia
%all comment
%
a tricky\\%test % case
another \\\%one % to mess with you
```

Comment: I confess I do not know the syntax `$-[0]` and `$+[0]`. Where is it documented?

Comment: @JacobWegelin In perlvar. They track the positions of where the RE and any captures in it matched in the string.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@- and https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@+. Both responders' answers solve the problem. Neither solves the (perhaps insoluble) problem of doing it all in one line of code, but that is okay. Both you and @ikegami have been helpful professors at the University of Stackoverflow, patient teachers.

Comment: @Jacob Wegelin, Re "*Neither solves the (perhaps insoluble) problem of doing it all in one line of code*", What are you talking about? Mine does! (Well, any program can be placed on one line since Perl doesn't need line breaks, but mine's a single statement.) And in addition to being much simpler, mine should also be way faster.

Comment: @ikegami because "Each variable must be defined, although it might be equal to the empty string." When there is no comment, your code produces 2 undefined variables. Subsequently they have to be set to the empty string. Perhaps instead of "one line of code" I should have said "one command." One thing that ends in a semicolon?

Comment: It's a weird thing to want them to be an empty string, but a simple little map would do: `map $_ // "",`. You really couldn't figure out how to set them to an empty string if they're undef?

Comment: @ikegami, could you put the map command into your answer? That way, we can see how it works in relation to the other code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```perl
my ($a1code, $a2boundary, $a3cmnt) =
   /
      ^
      (  (?: [^\\%]+ | \\. )* )
      (?: (%) (.*) )?
      \z
   /sx;
```

It does not consider `%` escaped in `abc\\%def` since the preceding `\` is escaped.

It requires no backtracking, and it always matches.

`$a1code` is always a string. It can be zero characters long (when the input is an empty string and when `%` is the first character), or the entire input string (when there is no unescaped `%`).

However, `$a2boundary` and `$a3cmnt` are only defined if there's an unescaped `%`. In other words, `$a2boundary` is equivalent to `defined($a3cmnt) ? '%' : undef`.

**Explanation**: `[^\\%]+` matches non-escaped characters other than `\` and `%`. `\\.` matches escaped characters. So `(?: [^\\%]+ | \\. )*` gets us the prefix, or the entire string if there are no unescaped `%`.

Comment: Why `/s` when we read the file one line at a time?

Comment: I don't read anything. But now importantly, I want to match any character. I have no reason to exclude line feed. But feel free to remove the `s` and add `\n` to the character class of that makes more sense to you. But it just makes things more complicated

Comment: How I would have written it (before studying your answer) would have been less robust.  If we replace \z with $ or \Z, then we can dispense with /s, and it will still work. But suppose we also changed to $/='', reading one paragraph at a time; then my syntax fails whereas yours still works.